# cannot connect to daemon at '/unix/var/nix/daemon-socket/socket'

Tags: nix

I am trying to start using nix but I encountered this issue when I run `darwin-rebuild switch`.

```
error: while evaluating the attribute 'activationScript' of the derivation 'darwin-system-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6+darwin4.0000000' at /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:201:11:
while evaluating the attribute 'activationScripts.script.text' at undefined position:
while evaluating 'g' at /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/lib/attrsets.nix:298:19, called from undefined position:
while evaluating anonymous function at /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/lib/modules.nix:140:72, called from /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/lib/attrsets.nix:301:20:
while evaluating the attribute 'value' at /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/lib/modules.nix:525:9:
while evaluating the option `system.activationScripts.script.text':
while evaluating the attribute 'mergedValue' at /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/lib/modules.nix:557:5:
while evaluating the attribute 'values' at /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/lib/modules.nix:551:9:
while evaluating the attribute 'values' at /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/lib/modules.nix:650:7:
while evaluating anonymous function at /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/lib/modules.nix:537:28, called from /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/lib/modules.nix:537:17:
while evaluating definitions from `/nix/store/7l4y20byz42j9xbppwzdmkg71apd73qh-darwin/darwin/modules/system/activation-scripts.nix':
while evaluating 'dischargeProperties' at /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/lib/modules.nix:609:25, called from /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/lib/modules.nix:538:137:
while evaluating the attribute 'value' at /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/lib/modules.nix:392:44:
while evaluating the attribute 'shell' at /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/generic/default.nix:125:14:
while evaluating the attribute 'bash' at /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/darwin/default.nix:544:14:
while evaluating 'addMetaAttrs' at /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/lib/meta.nix:15:28, called from /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix:10096:10:
while evaluating 'callPackageWith' at /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/lib/customisation.nix:117:35, called from /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix:10096:19:
while evaluating 'makeOverridable' at /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/lib/customisation.nix:67:24, called from /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/lib/customisation.nix:121:8:
while evaluating anonymous function at /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/pkgs/shells/bash/4.4.nix:1:1, called from /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/lib/customisation.nix:69:16:
while evaluating the attribute 'cc.bintools' at /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/generic/default.nix:173:14:
while evaluating 'mkCC' at /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/darwin/default.nix:108:14, called from /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/darwin/default.nix:123:50:
while evaluating anonymous function at /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/pkgs/build-support/cc-wrapper/default.nix:8:1, called from /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/darwin/default.nix:108:25:
while evaluating the attribute 'args' of the derivation 'Libsystem-1238.60.2' at /nix/store/gjqpc2i5nbi1yrzm0caaryvs8y1nhc8h-nixpkgs-21.11pre292293.84aa23742f6/nixpkgs/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:201:11:
cannot connect to daemon at '/nix/var/nix/daemon-socket/socket': Connection refused
```

I have searched around but I cannot find a solution for this. What can I do?

Comment: It seems like your nix-daemon isn't running. Is your Nix installation supposed to run a nix-daemon? If `/nix/store` isn't owned by your user, you need the nix-daemon.

Comment: Possibly a reboot is necessary.

Comment: On Debian at least, you need to add the users manually to group nix-users (and relogin).